# question about etale base change

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I know that, if $R \to S$ is a finite étale algebra, one can cover $\mathrm{Spec} R$ with étale morphisms $R \to R'$ such that $S \otimes_R R' \cong R' \times \ldots \times R'$. This is for example tag [04HN](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04HN).

Let's suppose now that $R$ is a DVR. Can I take an $R'$ as above such that $R'$ is also a DVR and $R \to R'$ is finite étale?

Maybe this is an easy question, but I come from a more geometric background and I am not sure about where to read about these sort of statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible if $R$ is connected and [Henselian](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04GG). In short: take a Galois cover dominating your given cover. Let me know if these assumptions are not good enough for your purposes (I would guess they are?).

> **Proposition:** *Suppose that $R\to S$ is a finite etale algebra with $R$ connected. Then, there exists a finite etale algebra $R\to R'$ such that $R'\otimes_R S$ is isomorphic to $(R')^n$ for some $n$. We may take $R'$ to be connected.*

*Proof:* Suppose first that $S$ is connected. Note then that $\mathrm{Spec}(S)\to\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ has clopen image, and thus is surjective. In other words, $\mathrm{Spec}(S)\to\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ is a finite etale cover. Let $\mathrm{Spec}(S')\to\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ be a Galois cover dominating $\mathrm{Spec}(S)\to\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ (combine [this](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BNB) and [this](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BMQ)). Note that $S'\otimes_R S'\cong (S')^m$ where $n$ is the degree of $R\to S'$. Indeed, if you think about this in terms of Galois categories, this is just the observation that the $\pi_1(S')$-action on $S'\otimes_R S'$ is obviously trivial. We have a morphism $\mathrm{Spec}(S'\otimes_R S)\to \mathrm{Spec}(S'\otimes_R S')$ over $\mathrm{Spec}(S')$. Observe though that this morphism is automatically finite etale by the cancellation property of finite etale morphisms (see below). Let $C$ be a connected component of $\mathrm{Spec}(S'\otimes_R S)$. Then, $C$ maps finite etalely to a connected component of $\mathrm{Spec}(S'\otimes_R S')$ which is, by assumption, $\mathrm{Spec}(S')$, and this morphism is over $\mathrm{Spec}(S')$. But we then have a finite etale map $C\to\mathrm{Spec}(S')$ over $\mathrm{Spec}(S')$ which then must be degree $1$, so an isomorphism. So, each connected component of $\mathrm{Spec}(S'\otimes_R S)$ is isomorphic to $\mathrm{Spec}(S')$ as desired. If $S$ is not connected, take a Galois cover dominating each connected component and argue similarly.$\blacksquare$

> **Lemma (Cancellation property):** *Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are finite etale $C$-algebras. Then, any $C$-algebra map $A\to B$ over $C$ is finite etale.*

*Proof:* By the cancellation principle (see 11.2.1 of [Vakil](https://math.stanford.edu/%7Evakil/216blog/FOAGjul3123public.pdf)), it suffices to show that if $C\to A$ is a finite etale morphism, then the map diagonal map $C\to C\otimes_A C$ is finite etale. But, as $C\to A$ is finite, and so separated, this map is a closed embedding. But, it is also an open embedding (see [this](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02GE)). Thus, it is a clopen embedding and so finite etale. $\blacksquare$

So, back to your question. By the proposition we can take a finite connected etale cover $R\to R'$ such that $S\otimes_R R'$ is isomorphic to $(R')^n$ for some $n$. But, as $R\to R'$ is finite etale we know that $R'$ is a Noetherian 1-dimensional and regular (e.g., see [this](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/025N) and [this](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/039S)). Moreover, by finiteness we know that $R'$ is semi-local. So, right now we have a semi-local Dedekind domain $R\to R'$ splitting $R\to S$. If we assume that $R$ is Henselian though, then $R'$'s connected components must be local, and thus DVRs. Since we assumed that $R'$ is connected, we deduce that $R'$ is a DVR as desired.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful reply. Do you know an example of a non-Henselian DVR where this fails?